# How to generate pom file for a gradle project with all dependencies?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I have a Gradle project which stores dependencies in toml file. I want to generate pom file with dependencies. This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    api ( libs.bundles.api) {
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'zookeeper')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'log4j')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'jsp-api')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', module: 'servlet-api')
    }
    compileOnly(libs.slf4j.api)
    testImplementation(libs.bundles.test.implementation)
    annotationProcessor(libs.lombok)
    testAnnotationProcessor(libs.lombok)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        customPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

When I run

> gradle publishToMavenLocal

I get pom file with dependencies only from libs.bundles.api. There aren't dependencies for scope compileOnly, testImplementation, annotationProcessor, testAnnotationProcessor. Please help to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A published POM file will only contain the runtime dependencies. The dependencies needed to consume and run the project. And that is correct.

> compileOnly

These are only needed to compile your project, and not needed to run your project.

> testImplementation

These are only needed to run the tests of your project and not needed to run it as a dependency.

> annotationProcessor

These are only used during the build of your project and are not needed to run it.

> testAnnotationProcessor

These are only needed during the build of your tests of your project and not needed for a consumer to use your project.

In order to do what you want, you need to customize the POM in publishing:

*build.gradle.kts*

This is in Kotlin DSL, but can easily be converted to Groovy DSL.

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("fakePom") {
            this.pom.withXml {
                val allDeps = project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies +
                    project.configurations.compileClasspath.get().resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies +
                    project.configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.get().resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies +
                    project.configurations.testCompileClasspath.get().resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies

                val root = asNode()

                root.children()
                    .filterIsInstance<Node>()
                    .map { it as Node }
                    .filter { "dependencies" == it.name() || "dependencyManagement" == it.name() }
                    .forEach {
                        root.remove(it)
                    }

                val ds = root.appendNode("dependencies")

                allDeps.forEach { d ->
                    val dn = ds.appendNode("dependency")
                    dn.appendNode("groupId", d.moduleGroup)
                    dn.appendNode("artifactId", d.name)
                    dn.appendNode("version", d.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
./gradlew generatePomFileForFakePomPublication
```

Comment: I want to enable Dependency Graph for my GitHub repository. Unfortunately, Dependency Graph doesn't support gradle, but Dependency Graph supports Maven. I want to create a fake pom file, to deceive Dependency Graph.

Comment: OK. Let me see what I find. As an FYI, in the future, it would be good to include an ultimate end result of what you are trying to accomplish as there may be an entirely different approach that is correct.

Comment: @Vlados Updated answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's working) How do you do it? Could you please give guides about this? I wanna figure out this thing

Comment: Yes, I read the Maven Publish plugin documentation and corresponding DSL and API docs. Also used Google.

Comment: It also helps when you have many years of experience with the Gradle DSL.